# My page navigation script don't show more than 150 posts. Can I change that?

Tags: javascript, pagination, blogger

I am using this script on a blogger blog but since my posts are more than 150 it shows only the first 150. Can I change that?

```
<div class='pagenavi'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
       var pageNaviConf = {
         perPage: 10,
         numPages: 9,
         firstText: &quot;First&quot;,
         lastText: &quot;Last&quot;,
         nextText: &quot;Next&quot;,
         prevText: &quot;Prev&quot;
       }
    </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  function pageNavi(o) {
    var m = location.href,
        l = m.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1,
        a = l ? m.substr(m.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, m.length) : "";
    a = a.indexOf("?") != -1 ? a.substr(0, a.indexOf("?")) : a;
    var g = l ? "/search/label/" + a + "?updated-max=" : "/search?updated-max=",
        k = o.feed.entry.length,
        e = Math.ceil(k / pageNaviConf.perPage);
    if (e <= 1) {
        return
    }
    var n = 1,
        h = [""];
    l ? h.push("/search/label/" + a + "?max-results=" + pageNaviConf.perPage) : h.push("/?max-results=" + pageNaviConf.perPage);
    for (var d = 2; d <= e; d++) {
        var c = (d - 1) * pageNaviConf.perPage - 1,
            b = o.feed.entry[c].published.$t,
            f = b.substring(0, 19) + b.substring(23, 29);
        f = encodeURIComponent(f);
        if (m.indexOf(f) != -1) {
            n = d
        }
        h.push(g + f + "&max-results=" + pageNaviConf.perPage)
    }
    pageNavi.show(h, n, e)
  }
  pageNavi.show = function(f, e, a) {
    var d = Math.floor((pageNaviConf.numPages - 1) / 2),
        g = pageNaviConf.numPages - 1 - d,
        c = e - d;
    if (c <= 0) {
        c = 1
    }
    endPage = e + g;
    if ((endPage - c) < pageNaviConf.numPages) {
        endPage = c + pageNaviConf.numPages - 1
    }
    if (endPage > a) {
        endPage = a;
        c = a - pageNaviConf.numPages + 1
    }
    if (c <= 0) {
        c = 1
    }
    var b = '<span class="pages">Pages ' + e + ' of ' + a + "</span> ";
    if (c > 1) {
        b += '<a href="' + f[1] + '">' + pageNaviConf.firstText + "</a>"
    }
    if (e > 1) {
        b += '<a href="' + f[e - 1] + '">' + pageNaviConf.prevText + "</a>"
    }
    for (i = c; i <= endPage; ++i) {
        if (i == e) {
            b += '<span class="current">' + i + "</span>"
        } else {
            b += '<a href="' + f[i] + '">' + i + "</a>"
        }
    }
    if (e < a) {
        b += '<a href="' + f[e + 1] + '">' + pageNaviConf.nextText + "</a>"
    }
    if (endPage < a) {
        b += '<a href="' + f[a] + '">' + pageNaviConf.lastText + "</a>"
    }
    document.write(b)
  };
  (function() {
    var b = location.href;
    if (b.indexOf("?q=") != -1 || b.indexOf(".html") != -1) {
        return
    }
    var d = b.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14;
    if (d != 13) {
        var c = b.indexOf("?"),
            a = (c == -1) ? b.substring(d) : b.substring(d, c);
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/' + a + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=9999"><\/script>')
    } else {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=9999"><\/script>')
    }
  })();
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: can you give more details pls.

Comment: If you're asking whether you can change the behavior of code by modifying it then the answer is a resounding "Yes".  Now... What attempt have you made and what isn't working as expected?  For starters, you'll find that code is much easier to read and understand with the occasional carriage return and formatting whitespace.  Once you've formatted your code so you can read it, start debugging to better understand what it's doing.  Maybe rename some variables to make their purpose more apparent.  Find where this cutoff is actually happening.  Then you'll have found something to modify.

Comment: The only thing I tried to change, since I 'm not familiar with coding, is the max results line to 150 so that I could show the first 150 results on the first row of pages (15*10 posts) and then restart the row with next 150 posts. The result was showing first 10 posts on first page and on second page it started from no151 post. I didn't try something else cause I didn't want to destroy it totally!